# set html option value with optgroup in select field using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, optgroup

I tried to set the option value in the select field using

```
document.getElementById("select").value="android";
```

But i want it to store as "android" in the **optgroup** "phones"

Is there anyway to set value of **option with the optgroup value**.

Comment: The value of an option must be unique... are you having mutliple options with value `android`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The value of an select element should be unique, else while getting the value how would you find out which optgroup is selected*

That said, you can use a css selector to find the select element and then set its selected property

```
var opt = document.querySelector('#select optgroup[label="Phones"] [value="android"]');
if (opt) {
    opt.selected = true;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/878t9zkp/)